# IF/THEN/ELSE in R

Tags: r, if-statement, syntax

everyone.

Hopefully an easy syntax question. I'm trying to create a new variable in a table in R which would say "1" if my patient was in the age range I was looking at, or "0" for no. The age range I'm interested is between 2-155. The code is running without any errors, but it is not working. When I look in my table, the new variable will say 1 even though the age4 is 158 Here is what I have:

```
table$newvar <- if (table$age4>=2 && table$age4 <=155) {table$newvar=1} else {table$newvar=0}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: R is not SAS (nor SPSS). You need to study the basic tutorials and work through the examples. If whatever text you are using for that purpose does not explain the differences btwn `if` and `ifelse` then your  should throw it away. (Furthermore, your use of "=" is wrong.)

Answer (score 5):

Two changes should be made:

1. Use the vectorized `ifelse()` function to generate the new column data.
2. Use the vectorized `&` logical-AND operator when combining the results of the comparisons.

---

```
table <- data.frame(age4=seq(1,200,10));
table$newvar <- ifelse(table$age4>=2 & table$age4<=155,1,0);
table;
##    age4 newvar
## 1     1      0
## 2    11      1
## 3    21      1
## 4    31      1
## 5    41      1
## 6    51      1
## 7    61      1
## 8    71      1
## 9    81      1
## 10   91      1
## 11  101      1
## 12  111      1
## 13  121      1
## 14  131      1
## 15  141      1
## 16  151      1
## 17  161      0
## 18  171      0
## 19  181      0
## 20  191      0
```

---

The reason your code is not working is because the `if` statement and the `&&` operator are not vectorized. The `&&` operator only examines the first element of each operand vector, and only returns a one-element vector representing the result of the logical-AND on those two input values. The `if` statement always expects a one-element vector for its conditional, and executes the if-branch if that element is true, or the else-branch if false.

If you use a multiple-element vector as the conditional in the `if` statement, you get a warning:

```
if (c(T,F)) 1 else 0;
## [1] 1
## Warning message:
## In if (c(T, F)) 1 else 0 :
##   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

But for some odd reason, you *don't* get a warning if you use a multiple-element vector as an operand to `&&` (or `||`):

```
c(T,F) && c(T,F);
## [1] TRUE
```

That's why your code appeared to succeed (by which I mean it didn't print any warning message), but it didn't actually do what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

When used in arithmetic `TRUE` and `FALSE` become `1` and `0` so:

```
transform(table, newvar = (age4 >= 2) * (age4 <= 155) )
```

These also work:

```
transform(table, newvar = as.numeric( (age4 >= 2) & (age4 <= 155) ) )

transform(table, newvar = ( (age4 >= 2) & (age4 <= 155) ) + 0 )

transform(table, newvar = ifelse( (age4 >= 2) & (age4 <= 155), 1, 0) )

transform(table, newvar = (age4 %in% 2:155) + 0) # assuming no fractional ages
```